# $resource delete method doesn't work right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am learning Angluarjs's $resource. I set a button on HTML for deleting a record from a json file,and hope to delete one record from testForm.json file. Unfortunately, I failed to do so and can't solve the problem.

The codes are here: [my Angularjs code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ezoszx66QnktSSqBapao?p=preview)
The deleting function in controller codes is shown as follows

```
$scope.deleteRecord = function () {
            var id = 1;
            var arecord = new singleResource();
            arecord.$get({userId:id},function () {
                $log.info(arecord);
                arecord.$delete();
            });
```

The HTML part of the deleting function is shown here:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-2">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteRecord()">Delete information</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

"$scope.deleteRecord" is the function that when clicking the Delete information button, the record with id=1 in json file should be removed. The error says:"DELETE http://localhost:3000/contactInfo 404 (Not Found) :3000/contactInfo:1 ", while the "arecord" is shown as an object in the log "m {email: "333@333", password: 321, method: "Internet", id: 1, $promise: undefined…}", which should be fine.

Comment: I suppose it is the wrong verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$http**

> $http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
>
> $http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
>
> **$http** is built into Angular, so there’s no need for the extra overhead of loading in an external dependency. $http is good for quick
>   retrieval of server-side data that doesn’t really need any specific
>   structure or complex behaviors. It’s probably best injected directly
>   into your controllers for simplicity’s sake.

**$resource**

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked >with the following parameters:
>
> HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
>
> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
>
> **$resouce** is good for situations that are slightly more complex than $http. It’s good when you have pretty structured data, but you
>   plan to do most of your crunching, relationships, and other operations
>   on the server side before delivering the API response. $resource
>   doesn’t let you do much once you get the data into your JavaScript
>   app, so you should deliver it to the app in its final state and make
>   more REST calls when you need to manipulate or look at it from a
>   different angle.

*Alternatively you could use: restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular*

> **Restangular** is a perfect option for complex operations on the client side. It lets you easily attach custom behaviors and interact
>   with your data in much the same way as other model paradigms you’ve
>   used in the past.

Angularjs guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete

try with the delete method:

```
$scope.deleteRecord = function () {
            var id = 1;
            var arecord = new singleResource();
            arecord.$delete({userId:id},function () {
                $log.info(arecord);
                //arecord.$delete();
            });
```

or

```
$http({
  method: 'DELETE',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Another question still confusing me is that when to use $http service and when to use $resource service to communicate with the server side? or which one is better? Does $resource service need successCallback and errorCallback functions when using?